# confusement on correct Carrierwave image_tag path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

Im unable to find out the correct path for inclusion of my Carrierwave image.
After many searching and trying all possible combinations I hope someone knows here:

I have

asset.rb

```
belongs_to :attachable,
           :polymorphic => true

mount_uploader :file, AssetUploader
```

profile.rb

```
  has_many :assets, :as => :attachable
```

In my views I use

```
= image_tag @profile.assets.first.file_url(:search) rescue nil
```

but this includes the very first image ever uploaded.

In say a _profile.haml partial I would like to add the image that belongs to that current_user how could this be done?

```
My uploader

    class AssetUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^[:word:]\.\-\+]/

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  process :resize_to_fill => [600, 600]

  version :profile do
    process :resize_to_fill => [300, 300]
  end

  version :search do
    process :resize_to_fill => [124, 124]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [96, 96]
  end

  version :small do
    process :resize_to_fill => [48, 48]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

  def filename
    "#{secure_token(10)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end


  def default_url
    "/images/" + [version_name, "avatar_default.jpg"].compact.join('_')
  end


  protected

  def secure_token(length=32)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end


end
```

Comment: having the same issue. It works unless there are no assets then I don't get the correct URL.  Did you find a fix for this.  I'm having the same issue right now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like this?

```
= image_tag current_user.profiles.assets.file_url(:search) rescue nil
```